# How to set the right fragment to replace.

Tags: android

I’m doing a navigation drawer in my android app. On my `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` function i try on item select to change the current fragment into a new one. The problem is that when I change the current fragment its take the initial status of it. maybe because i'm doing this way 
`fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.cont, new SessionsFragement())
                        .commit();`
I declare a new instance of my fragment and i think it’s normal, its display me the initial status of the thing. On my fragment i've try to set a textView to see if i will say it when i call the fragement from tha navigation drawer but it's not the case.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

     View  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spot, container, false);

    tata = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tata);

    tata.setText("karim");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spot, container, false);

}
```

So please can anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet you posted you are inflating again the view. You should return the one you modified

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spot, container, false);
    tata = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tata);
    tata.setText("karim");
    return v;
 }
```